# Run Rails Tests without Dropping Test Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle11g

Just wondering if there's a way to run Rails tests without dropping the database. I'm currently only executing unit tests and am using the following rake command to do so: `rake test:units`.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Just in case this is relevant:

- Rails 3
- Ruby 1.8.7 (MRI)
- Oracle 11g Database

  - activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, I have found that there isn't a way to do this. The test rake tasks will always drop the database, even when providing the **`TEST=`** option as Bohdan suggests.

By using the **`--trace`** option, this can be proven. Here is the output:

```
$ rake test:units TEST=test/unit/post_test.rb --trace
(in /Users/johnnyicon/Development/ror/test-app)
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
```

Reading through the [Ruby on Rails Guides for Testing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#preparing-your-application-for-testing), it describes what some of these rake tasks mean. The one to pay particular attention to is the **`db:test:load`** task, which you see on the 7th line from the bottom of the output as **`** Execute db:test:load`**. The guides say the following about this task:

> Recreate the test database from the
>   current schema.rb

So even if I were to execute the unit tests one by one as Bohdan suggests, the rake task would still recreate the database. Not the answer I was hoping for, but it isn't a problem anymore.

The reason I was asking to begin with was because I did not have access to another database to use for testing, so I was using my development database for testing as well. But since then, I've been able to get another database dedicated for testing.

Thanks anyway Bohdan! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Your test database *should* be cleared out each time you run tests, otherwise your tests will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5 (and possibly earlier versions), just comment-out the following line in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
 ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

This will prevent `rake test` or `rspec` from attempting to drop your test DB. You'll need to run migrations manually as well.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 5.2 this behaviour can be modified setting `maintain_test_schema` to `false` in `test/test_helper.rb` before importing `rails/test_help`:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.maintain_test_schema = false
require "rails/test_help"
```

`rails/test_help` will check the value of `maintain_test_schema` to decide if it has to drop/create/migrate the test database or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old post that does the monkey patching of overriding purge/load tasks:
http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2007/09/22/making-rails-raketest-not-drop-your-pgsql-database/

Comment: Similar answers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24785428/680464 ---- and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8112074/680464

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a way to skip Rails' default behavior, try adding this to your Rakefile:

```
Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].clear
Rake::Task["db:test:load"].clear
Rake::Task["db:test:purge"].clear
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you not write a custom Rake task that monkey patched the Rake db:test:load task to do nothing?