# Overriding rails' default rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a Rails 2.2 project in which I want to override the functionality of the `rake db:test:prepare` task.  I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
#lib/tasks/db.rake
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    desc "Overridden version of rails' standard db:test:prepare task since the schema dump used in that can't handle DB enums"  
    task :prepare => [:environment] do
      puts "doing db:structure:dump"
      Rake::Task['db:structure:dump'].invoke
      puts "doing db:test:clone_structure"
      Rake::Task['db:test:clone_structure'].invoke
    end   
  end
end
```

I get the standard task's behaviour.  If I change the name of the task to `:prepare2` and then do `rake db:test:prepare2`, then it works fine.  The natural conclusion I draw from this is that my rake tasks are being defined *before* the built-in Rails ones, so mine is overridden by the standard `:prepare` task.

Can anyone see how I can fix this?  I'd rather override it than have to use a new task.  Thanks, max

Comment: Maybe you can directly modify the Rakefile in RAILS_ROOT?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you define a rake task that already exists, its execution gets appended to the original task's execution; both tasks will be executed.

If you want to redefine a task you need to clear the original task first:

```
Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].clear
```

It's also useful to note that once a task has been executed in rake, it won't execute again even if you call it again. This is by design but you can call `.reset` on a task to allow it to be run again.

Comment: Ah, looks like that also works and is a much nicer syntax.  thanks!

Comment: No worries :) I think that might be the first time someone has accepted an answer of mine! :D

Comment: This can fail if the task in question doesn't exist (for example if you're running in a production vs development mode). To make it work even when the task doesn't exist, create an implicit empty task first: `task :default => []; Rake::Task[:default].clear`

Comment: Rake::Task.clear
Rake::Task['rake_task'].reenable
Rake::Task['rake_task'].invoke

Is this ok?

Answer (score 13):

You have to remove the default task before adding your own:

```
Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:test:prepare')
namespace 'db' do
  namespace 'test' do
    task 'prepare' do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

A [fairly popular idiom](https://github.com/search?authenticity_token=585d7108e3b47eff315670288d044c8b4384770a&langOverride=&q=def%20remove_task&repo=&start_value=1&type=Code) is to create a convenience method called `remove_task` like so:

```
Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
  def remove_task(task_name)
    @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
  end
end

def remove_task(task_name)
  Rake.application.remove_task(task_name)
end
```

([Source: `drnic/newgem`](https://github.com/drnic/newgem))

Comment: Thanks Alex, the top one is fine for me and also more obvious as to what's going on, for the sake of anyone else who looks at it.  Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Create a new *project.rake* file at **lib/tasks/**, and paster below code into it.

```
namespace :mv do
desc "Display hint and info for your rails 4 project"
task info: :environment do
    puts 'Run rake test to test'
end
end

task(:default).clear.enhance ['mv:info']
```

inspired by [Krasimir Angelov's blog](http://blog.codingspree.net/2012/04/26/overwriting_rake_spec_task.html)