# Why does default rake task run specs in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I have one app that runs the specs with just `rake`, but don't know where or how this task is defined. There are no tasks in lib/tasks.

Part of Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'oauth2'
  gem 'rack_session_access'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

RSpec gems:

```
guard-rspec (4.5.0)
rspec (3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
rspec-rails (3.1.0)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
```

I'm using Rake 10.4.2 and Rails 4.1.6.

Also, when I add:

```
task :default do
  puts 'No default task.'
end
```

to the Rakefile, first it runs the specs, and then prints "No default task."

EDIT: Add Rakefile

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding rails' default rake tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112074/overriding-rails-default-rake-tasks)

Comment: Looks like it could be rspec-rails adding `spec` as a dependency of the default task: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/6d1b893b936e6651fbb96771fefdefff8a7627fe/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L6

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have `rspec-rails` in your Gemfile, then when the gem is loaded by Rails is will execute this line:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.2.1/lib/rspec-rails.rb#L19

```
load "rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake"
```

which in turn defines the default rake task:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L6

```
task :default => :spec
```

That's why the default rake task runs the specs in your Rails app.

Furthermore, when you added this code:

```
task :default do
  puts 'No default task.'
end
```

That does not in fact redefine the default task: it augments it. The way that Rake task definition works, each declaration of the same task name *adds to that task*. It does not redefine it. Hence the result that you see "No default task" *and* the specs are run.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But I have the same gem in another Rails app and get `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'`. I wonder how to figure out why it doesn't have the rake task.

Comment: @BSeven I suggest opening a separate question for that, along with the Gemfile and Rakefile of the Rails app that has the `don't know how to build task 'default'` problem.

Comment: Is there any way of removing the `spec` task dependency from the `default` task?