# Change Rails/Rake Test Default Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the [Rails guide for testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing):

> "By default, running bin/rails test won't run your system tests. Make sure to run bin/rails test:system to actually run them."

Does anyone know how to change the default behavior so it will run all of your tests including system tests?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same.

I think that for having `rails test` to also run system tests you need to redefine the rake task. For what I could investigate the task is defined at `testing.rake` file inside the railties gem `/lib` directory:

```
desc "Runs all tests in test folder except system ones"
  task :test do
  $: << "test"
  if ENV.key?("TEST")
    Minitest.rake_run([ENV["TEST"]])
  else
    Minitest.rake_run(["test"], ["test/system/**/*"])
  end
end
```

The second argument in the function inside `else` is a pattern to exclude when running the tests.

Here [Overriding rails' default rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116584/8267417)
  it's explained how to override them, however I couldn't put it to work this way.

If it helps you, I'm using `bundle exec rake test:system test` instead and it runs **both** the system and all the other tests together